# Soft keyboard hides parts of fullscreen webview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a native Android app that is a wrapper for a webpage. It works pretty well, but there is an issue where the soft keyboard (Android keyboard) appears over the bottom of the webview, which makes it impossible to see what you are writing if you are trying to fill out something near the bottom of the webview.

Please see image below. Here I've clicked a textarea that is impossible to reach while the keyboard is open:

[image]

The code for this view is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp" tools:context=".PetpulseMainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/petpulseWebView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried switching the `RelativeLayout` with `ScrollView` and other approaches I've found, but for some reason the keyboard is always rendered on top of the view.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name=".PetpulseMainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
         [...]
</activity>
```

Comment: please provide how is activity declared at `AndroidManifest`

Comment: Your activity seems to be `FullScreen`. Remove the fullScreen theme

Comment: @gio - Added activity xml.

Comment: @vinitius - Simply removing the `FullScreen` worked. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known bug as refered in :

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5497

To avoid it, remove the `FullScreen` theme of your activity

**Update:**

From [FLAG_FULLSCREEN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

> Window flag: hide all screen decorations (such as the status bar)
>   while this window is displayed. This allows the window to use the
>   entire display space for itself -- the status bar will be hidden when
>   an app window with this flag set is on the top layer. A fullscreen
>   window will ignore a value of SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE for the
>   window's softInputMode field; the window will stay fullscreen and will
>   not resize.