# EditText parent layout hidden by soft keyboard with adjustPan in full screen

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout that is full screen needed for some custom scrolling & custom background on the action bar.

I have a RelativeLayout with a FrameLayout (match_parent for width, wrap_content for height) at the top left and a RelativeLayout at the bottom left.  I set the activity to adjustPan.  I have an EditText in the bottom-left RelativeLayout.  The EditText moves up when it has focus & the keyboard appears.  BUT, its RelativeLayout parent does not full scroll up and is partially hidden on the bottom by the keyboard.  I want to make sure the entire parent layout is visible just above the keyboard.

How do I accomplish that?

Things I've tried: stateVisible|adjustResize, just adjustResize, messed with isScrollContainer (both true & false) on the parent layout and others up the view hierarchy.  All without success.

Environment: Android Studio 1.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.10, Using ActionBarActivity, testing on API 21, but min API 14.

Comment: Please, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155577/soft-keyboard-hides-parts-of-fullscreen-webview/28155820#28155820

Comment: I don't think that's what I want.  I need the activity to remain full screen for a hero image (see Google I/O videos) AND still need the system button bar at the bottom.

Comment: Ok, but that's the default behavior. A possible workaround is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417123/android-how-to-adjust-layout-in-full-screen-mode-when-softkeyboard-is-visible/19494006#19494006

Comment: Default behavior for what?  I don't follow.  If you mean resize not working on fullscreen, I figured that much out from other questions.  My layout is basically:

<RelativeLayout><FrameLayout /><RelativeLayout><EditText /></RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>

I want the inner RelativeLayout to be just above the keyboard, but its partially obscured b/c there's padding between the bottom of the EditText and the RelativeLayout.